# Lots of little NG-IF versus Few NG-IF but with a lot of code inside

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

I have page with lots of little variations on elements and images.
They're controlled by a filter, which "show/hide" elements from the user.

Right now, I have a single file(component) with many ngIf's controlling this show/hide, and these conditions eventually become big ifs like these:

```
*nfIf="condition1 && (!condition2 || !condition3)"
```

This component will repeat in a list. So the ngFor will replicate these tests for every component.

So in terms of **performance**(forgeting DRY) on Angular. If I change my approach to use less IF's, like only 5, but replicating blocks of code, one after another.

Will it run faster? I'm picturing the browser checking and testing every condition.  Any clue?

Comment: Browsers have profilers now. Use that to decide if your changes are improving performance. Poorly maintainable code is often poorly performing. Ignoring maintenance is how you paint yourself into a corner later where you can't fix poor performance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could consider adding a property to your component like this:

```
get isConditions(): boolean {
  if (condition1 && (!condition2 || !condition3)) {
    return true;
  }
  return false;
}
```

Then you would not need to repeat the full set of conditions on the elements.